# Why, when trying to set the frame it doesn't work

Tags: html, frame

i have to do homework which should look like this: 
[frame homework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIDBx.png)

i managed to do: ([my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms2oC.png))

```
<HTML>
<frameset cols="*,200">
<frameset rows="100,*,15%">
<frame src="rl_gorna.html">
<frame src="rl_srodkowa.html">
<frameset cols="15%,*">
<frame src="rld_lewa.html">
<frame src="rld_prawa.html">
</frameset>

</HTML>
```

But i dont know how to do right side because It breaks all the time. I thought that when i will add over "frameset rows="100,*,15%" frame src it will work fine but its not

Comment: What school is teaching framesets in 2020? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Comment: Polish school xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you get the nesting in order, and don't forget to close your `<frameset>` elements:

```
<frameset cols="*,200">
    <frameset rows="100,*,15%">
        <frame src="rl_gorna.html">
        <frame src="rl_srodkowa.html">
        <frameset cols="15%,*">
            <frame src="rld_lewa.html">
            <frame src="rld_prawa.html">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
    <frame src="r_prawa.html">
</frameset>
```

See a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sound-ur3ir)

And a friendly note: `<frame>` and `<frameset>` elements are deprecated, so I'd put them to rest when your homework is done.

Comment: Thank you for help!